# How to select masks with feature among only black ones- semantic segmentation

Tags: semantic-segmentation

I'm working on a very unbalanced dataset for semantic segmentation. The majority case of image's masks have only background (0 pixels) and no feature (1 pixels) leading to a very biased and unefficient Unet networks.
I'm looking for a code to select (from folders) only masks, and corresponding images with at least one feature to segment. Any possible idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a lot of ways to achieve this, but the first one that comes to my mind is to check if there are non-zeros values in your mask.

You forgot to tell us what framework do you use, so let's assume it's python, but you could try something like :

```py
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2

numpy_images_array = list()
numpy_masks_array = list()

for mask_path, img_path in zip(os.listdir(MASKS_DIR), os.listdir(IMG_DIR)):
    mask = cv2.imread(mask_path)
    if np.any(mask!=0) :   # or: if len(np.unique(mask))>1
        numpy_masks_array.append(mask)
        numpy_images_array.append(cv2.imread(img_path))
```